# force query to return duplicate values sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a simple query

```
SELECT table1.no,table1.surname,table2.gender FROM table1 JOIN table2 on table1.no= table2.no WHERE table1.no in ('123','456','789','123')
```

so when this query runs and returns output it only shows 3 rows

```
table1.no table1.surname table2.gender
123             sss             m
456             aaa             f
789             qqq             m
```

but i want the output to be repeated like below

```
table1.no table1.surname table2.gender
123             sss             m
456             aaa             f
789             qqq             m 
123             sss             m
```

is there a way i can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in a collection rather than using an `IN` filter:

```sql
SELECT t1.no,
       t1.surname,
       t2.gender
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (t1.no = t2.no)
       INNER JOIN TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(123,456,789,123)) l
       ON (t1.no = l.COLUMN_VALUE);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (no, surname) AS
SELECT 123, 'm' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'f' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'm' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (no, gender) AS
SELECT 123, 'm' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'f' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'm' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NO | SURNAME | GENDER |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123 | m | m |
> | 456 | f | f |
> | 789 | m | m |
> | 123 | m | m |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=86abd81df832ddf34dd267748220ade0)*

Answer (score 0):

I think the default join type in Oracle is an INNER JOIN, which will remove duplicates. Try switching the JOIN to a LEFT JOIN:

```sql
SELECT table1.no,table1.surname,table2.gender FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.no= table2.no WHERE table1.no in ('123','456','789','123')
```

Comment: didnt seem to work